# Fork is not a heroku command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, heroku-cli

I'm trying to change my Heroku app region by following this official guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-migration.

The problem is that, when I try to fork it at the very beginning using: `heroku fork --from sourceapp --to targetapp --region eu`.

Heroku cli returns:

```
 !    fork is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant info
 !    Run heroku help for a list of available commands.
```

I'm using the latest version of Heroku Cli 6.15.18-fdf2097 in Windows 10

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**heroku-fork says**

Heroku CLI plugin to fork an existing app into a new app.

**DEPRECATED:** Heroku fork is deprecated as a core command. It will no longer be included in the CLI by default 2017-12-01. See [Developing CLI Plugins](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/developing-cli-plugins) for more information on developing plugins.

You need to install `heroku-fork` plugin

[**Installation**](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-fork#installation)

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-fork
```

More info see [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-fork)

Hope it helps

Comment: Why they think not to mention this if review-apps _doesn't_ work for your use case is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: The suggested replacement is *review-apps* but the only way to get those working is by using GitHub as your source control...? 

Comment: super annoying that this is necessary. Heroku used to be so easy to use.